# Show value of column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

In a dgv cell, I want to show a specific value from a list. Dgv shows `list<apartment>`, class Apartment has class Owner which has OwnerName. I want dgv to show OwnerName, now it shows App.Owner

```
public class Owner
{        
    public string OwnerName{get;set;}       
}
public class Apartment
{
    public Owner Owns{ get; set; }
}
public List<Apartment> ApartmentsList
dgv.DataSource = ApartmentsList
```

Comment: @LarsTech did it, thank you for help

Comment: Put `public override string ToString() { return OwnerName; }` in your Owner class.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you very much, it works :)

Comment: We don't put answers in the question here.  Feel free to post your own answer instead and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding public override stirng ToString to Owner class will fix this.

```
public class Owner
{        
    public string OwnerName{get;set;}  
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return OwnerName;
    }     
}
```